# Vertical alignment with Prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

is it possible to configure Prettier to align vertically in such a way that this:

```
x = 12;
job = "programmer";
name = "Gabriel";
```

becomes this:

```
x    = 12;
job  = "programmer";
name = "Gabriel";
```

if Prettier doesn't allow it, can someone point me to another code formatter that does?

I know a bunch of extensions that do just that, the problem is that by using them I lose the advantages of a code formatter like prettier.

Ideally, I would like a code formatter that does everything Prettier does + makes whitespace better

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is not available in Prettier, and wont be:

https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8611

Kind of makes that unusable for us that want to align the code vertically.